# Can I insert Posts in WordPress via a standalone Tool

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a Blog witch daily Posts from different People who dont be very familiar with the WordPress Backend and how to set up a Blog Post. So I will build my own little standalone Tool where they can easy choise the Content of the Post and then the Tool will build the Strukture of the Post and send it to WordPress and publish it.
Is that possible with WordPress or do I need another CMS like Drupal or each other?

Thank you for helping me out.
Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For example using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it via email. Just google 'wp post via email.'